# Server removing .htaccess file. Could .gitignore be responsible?

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting, gitignore

I have a vps with a number of sites. One of them is having an issue where the .htaccess file is be deleted every 24hrs. I do not think it is an issue to do with the host as there are a good nuimber of similar sites with .htaccess on the same VPS.

Taking a look around I noticed a .gitignore file, unique to this site. To be honest I am not 100% sure what it does. Opening it I saw:

```
# ignore any files beginning with .
\.*

# except do not ignore .gitignore
!.gitignore
```

Could this be affecting my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out yes, .gitignore was responsible. I added:

```
# except do not ignore .gitignore
!.gitignore
!.htaccess
```